# How to refer or link the Java src with test structure in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to gradle currently I'm facing a problem while compiling test classes I'm referring the Java Classes in Test Classes to test program but I couldn't compile. Problem I wouldn't understand to how to link or refer Java src structure with test structure. Could somebody help me how to resolve the issues.

Below I provided the screenshot of Src and Test package structure and compilation problem.

**Java Src and Test structure**

[image: Src and Test Structure]

**Compilation Error**

[image: Compilation Error]

**build.properties**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.gradle.shopcart.ShopCartApp'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    // You can read more about how to add dependency here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

}
```

**EDIT::**

I'm using netbeans, with help of gradle plugin i created this project structure below you can find the screenshot. If I miss anything please correct me.

[image: Structure]

Please let me know in case of more information.

Comment: Generally the product classes in the **same package** should be available for the test classes. Can you verify that the package in your test class does not have a typo defining it in a different package than then product class?

Comment: There is no typo error, above I have given the detailed project structure. Do I missing anything else?